# autoColumnsDefinitions function doesn't load formatter or anything else

Tags: tabulator

**Setup**:

- Bootstrap 5
- Tabulator 5.4.4 with tabulator_bootstrap5.css
- Brave Browser on macos Ventura

**Intention**: treat all cells as html by default

**Attempted Solution**:
Format all cells as html cells by using the `autoColumnsDefinitions` function.
I used the function documented at https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/columns#autocolumns.

**Expected**:

- html links and formats are rendered correctly.
- header filters are available

**Actual Results**:

- html code is escaped and displayed
- no header filters
- the `autoColumnsDefinitions` function code seems never to run?

**Error Messages**

- none

---

#### HTML Table

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-sm" id="table-1">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/some/path/">Row 1</a></td>
            <td>plain</td>
            <td><i>running</i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/some/path/">Row 2</a></td>
            <td>nice</td>
            <td><b>walking</b></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Tabulator setup

```js
    var tableOne = new Tabulator("#table-1", {
        autoColumns: true,
        autoColumnsDefinitions: function(definitions) {
            //definitions - array of column definition objects
            definitions.forEach((column) => {
                column.headerFilter = true; // add header filter to every column
                column.formatter = "html";
            });
            return definitions;
        },
    });
```

#### Render result

[image: Screenshot of rendered result and code breakpoints]

Comment: There might be a general issue in how I set it up. The default code from Getting Started with tabledata having three rows won't render the rows, only the header.

Comment: Problem 1: autoColumnsDefinitions not executed was solved by adding the omitted `type` attribute to the `<script>` tag in HTML to be `<script type="application/javascript">`

Comment: The fact that the data:tabledata argument is unexpectedly required would pollute this question. I'll created a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75711176/data-attribute-unexpectedly-needed-for-html-tables
There's also a codepen to reproduce/play: https://codepen.io/voko-the-bashful/pen/yLxvLWM

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding the `data` argument to the Tabulator constructor call. The variable has to match the actual table layout. Assuming the table uses a `<thead>`, the data can be generated.

```js
//populate table header data from existing thead (ugly code)
tabledata = [];
let trow = {}
for (let c = 0, cell; cell = document.getElementById("table-1").tHead.rows[0].cells[c]; c++) {
    trow[cell.innerText] = "n/a";
}
tabledata.push(trow);

// init with data argument
var tableOne = new Tabulator("#table-1", {
    data: tabledata,
    autoColumns: true,
    autoColumnsDefinitions: function(definitions) {
        //definitions - array of column definition objects
        definitions.forEach((column) => {
            column.headerFilter = true; // add header filter to every column
            column.formatter = "html";
        });
        return definitions;
    },
});
```